# How does python collections accept multiple data types?

Tags: python, arrays, c

The most popular python version is CPython, written in C. What i want to know is how is it possible to write a python collection using C when C arrays can only store on type of data at the same time?

Comment: I assume that uniform type of data is a pointer to an object, and everything in python is of base-type `object`.

Comment: "The most popular python version is Cython" - you're thinking of CPython. Cython is a tool for writing C extensions for CPython.

Comment: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/

Comment: Thanks for the link and clarifications, I'll check that out!!

Comment: CPython is open source, why not check out the code: https://github.com/python/cpython

Answer (score 0):

This is not how python does it in C, but I've written a small interpreted language in Java (which also only allows arrays/lists with 1 data type) and implemented mixed type lists. I had a Value interface and a class for each type of value and those classes implemented the Value interface. I had FunctionValue class, a StringValue class, a BooleanValue class, and a ListValue class, all of which implemented the value interface. The ListValue class has a field of type `List<Value>` which contains the list's elements. All methods on the Value interface and its implementing classes which do stuff like numeric addition, string appending, list access, function calling, etc. initially take in Value objects and do different things based on which actual kind of Value it is.

You could do something similar in C, albeit at a lower level since it doesn't have interfaces and classes to help you manage your types.